# Cocoapods: using dynamic framework and library simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, dependency-management

I want to use `JCDialPad` and `Alamofire` at same time from CocoaPods. Below is how my pod file looks:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 2.4'
pod 'JCDialPad', :podspec => './podspec'
```

Note that JCDialPad is already having dependency on `libPhoneNumber-iOS`.

Now I have add my bridging header file in Build Settings and is detected properly. But my question here is Alamofire will be compiled and build as Dynamic Framework. But JCDialPad is **NOT** meant to be used as Dynamic Framework.

How will cocoapods podfile to be written so that only Alamofire and Kingfisher will be used as Dynamic Framework and JCDialPad will be used as Static Library?

Any hint will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking for is not possible at all. Please refer to the detailed discussion [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3839)